# Add a dynamic image in a ListView

Tags: java, android, xml

So, basically i'm working with a ListView, looking like this for the moment :

[image]
<sub>(source: [xooimage.com](http://img74.xooimage.com/files/9/7/5/sample1-2f8fa7a.jpg))</sub>

(As a new user I can't post images..)

I add each element of the list like that :

```
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("ing_name", "Mozzarella");
listItem.add(map);
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("ing_name", "Emmental");
listItem.add(map);
```

I would like to put a different picture for every element, to end up with something like that (I photoshoped it) :

[image]
<sub>(source: [xooimage.com](http://img74.xooimage.com/files/b/2/7/sample2-2f8fa8c.jpg))</sub>

I tried some things, but couldn't find out one working.
Does someone know how to do it ?

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Simple adapter class. The below link might be helpful.

[Simple adapter example](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/)

I hope it helps..

Comment: It looks fine, I'm gonna try that. Thanks ! :)